# Simple N1QL query to delete an entry from table with column name. And simple select statement using where condition for Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Simple N1QL query for performing an delete operation and selecting an database using N1QL. I have attached the screenshot for same.

For deleting from `Guardium2` table with column `EmpName`, I have tried this:

```
DELETE FROM `Guardium2` 
WHERE `EmpName` = 'test2'";
```

This doesn't help me out showing some syntax error:

[image]

For selecting an `Guardium2` where `EmpName` is test4 below I have tried some query that doesn't seem to be working.

```
SELECT * FROM `Guardium2` 
WHERE `EmpName` = 'test4'
```

This is the error I get:

[image]

Please help me out for some update operation as well. Updating an Guardium2 with EmpName as test4 -> test5

Following is the snapshot for table of Guardium2 or Document in Couchbase.

Note-> Whenever we delete or update the changes should reflect in Document section of Couchbase.

[image]

Comment: FYI, there aren't "tables" and "columns" in Couchbase. You've got buckets (plus scopes and collections in Server 7) and JSON fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM Guardium2 where EmpName = 'test2'";
```

The above statement is not properly closed quotes that why it gives syntax error. Correct statement will be

```
DELETE FROM Guardium2 where EmpName = 'test2';
```

N1QL requires index. Checkout documentation.

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON Guardium2(EmpName);
```

https://index-advisor.couchbase.com/indexadvisor/

Comment: The above query showing exception like this-
[
  {
    "code": 4000,
    "msg": "No index available on keyspace Guardium2 that matches your query. Use CREATE INDEX or CREATE PRIMARY INDEX to create an index, or check that your expected index is online.",
    "query": "DELETE FROM Guardium2 where EmpName = 'test4';"
  }
]

Comment: There index definition provided. Did you create one.